# how to open /dev/mem in non-root mode?

Tags: linux, file, fopen

I tried to open **/dev/mem**.
Accessing **/dev/mem** needs root permission to open the file.

But I can't use my program in super user. so I changed **/dev/mem** access permission as **666**(Don't consider about security issues!). but still, I cant open the file.

is there any way to open the file in non root mode?

Comment: You can't. Because it's a massive security hole.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Access to `/dev/mem` is a privileged operation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your user to kmem group?
If you need just read permission it may work.

Answer (score 0):

At your file change the owner and set permissions 4755.

```
sudo chown root FILE
sudo chmod 4755 FILE
```